# how to use Rails' belongs_to default option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to do some amount of logic before fetching a belongs_to association record, like this contrived example:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: blogs
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
end
```

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  blog_id    :integer
#
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog, default: -> { 
    puts 'here'
    Blog.first
  }
end
```

by doing `post.blog` I was expecting to get the first Blog and to see the text "here" (doing this in rails console)

Instead I am getting the actual Blog from post.blog_id.

What am I doing wrong here and how can do some Ruby logic when calling the association? (scope will not work for me as I want to do things other than AR queries)

edit: the ActiveRecord tests here lead me to believe my assumption is correct and the above code should work as I expect https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/test/cases/associations/belongs_to_associations_test.rb#L186

Comment: I would guess that the `default` block is only called when the association would otherwise return nil.

Comment: `default` is used to Provide a callable (i.e. proc or lambda) to specify that the association should be initialized with a particular record before validation. Validation isn't run on new it is only run on validate, save or create. Also, in the test they are calling a method from the proc. IMO, if you need to write more than one line of code use a method, don't do it in the proc.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but hopefully this helps anyone searching as I have.

As per the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#default) the default option on `belongs_to` is a boolean that determines whether the association's presence will be checked in validation. This is likely to support values being defaulted after validation.

##### Solution

The way I have implemented a default for an association like this is to override the attribute's get method e.g.

```
belongs_to :blog, optional: true

# If the blog association is blank, get the first blog
def blog
  @blog ||= super || Blog.first
end
```

###### NOTE

This only works when directly calling `blog`. This doesn't actually default the association in your database, so ActiveRecord database operations (such as `where`, `joins`, `select` etc.) will **NOT** work.

For that, it would be recommended to use a `before_create` callback to set the default value, e.g.

```
belongs_to :blog, default: true
before_create :set_blog

def set_blog
  self.blog ||= Blog.first
end
```